# Direction markers leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I'm trying to make 2 markers with polyline using leaflet :

the 2 marker icon is car.

My code is:

```
L.marker([lat, long], { icon: icon }).addTo(map); 
L.marker([latitude, longitude], { icon : CarIcon}).addTo(map);
 L.polyline([[geoLatLong.latitude, geoLatLong.longitude],
         [marker.RAlocation.latitude, marker.RAlocation.longitude]], 
         {
            color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
```

I want to change the direction icon car with the direction of polyline(same direction).

Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

I can see two solutions here.

The first one is to use the `L.Icon` custom icon from Leaflet. Especially setting a [div as icon](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon) :

```js
var myIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'my-div-icon'});
```

Creating a car should be easy enough with divs 
Then, dynamically set a rotate transform styling to the overall div icon according to the direction you want.

The second one is to use Leaflet svg layer so you can easily create the icon you want, even complex, as svg shapes.
And once again, set a rotate styling to the shape according to the direction.